# UI is not displaying changes from an array item in a react redux tool kit app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm developing a ToDo app with react-redux toolkit.I can read/display, insert and delete successfully but not update because the UI is not displaying changes made to to-dos, even though i see the changes in `Redux ToolsDev`.
I think `<ToDoList/>` component in charge of displaying all to-dos using an array from the state is not re-rendering because is not detecting changes in the array itself since the array item (todo) is the only one updated.
Code:
`toDoSlice`

```
const initialState = {
  toDos: [
    { id: nanoid(), text: "First ToDo" },
    { id: nanoid(), text: "Second ToDo" },
  ],
  text: "",
};
const toDoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "toDo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveChanges: (state, action) => {
      state.toDos[action.payload].text = state.text;
      //  updating other state values...
    },
  },
});
export const selectToDos = (state) => state.todo.toDos;
export const selectText = (state) => state.todo.text;
export const selectEditStatus = (state) => state.todo.editStatus;
export const { saveChanges } = toDoSlice.actions;
export default toDoSlice.reducer;
```

`<ToDoList/>` display todos from array

```
export default function ToDoList({ toDos }) {
  return (
    <form className="p-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "#F0E8E5" }}>
      <h2>List</h2>
      {toDos.map((todo) => (
        <ToDo key={todo.id} {...todo} />
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}
```

`<ToDo/>` display todo using an an id and text

```
export default function ToDo({ id, text }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="input-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={text} />
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-warning"
          onClick={() => dispatch(editToDo(id))}
        >
          Update
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={() => dispatch(deleteTodo(id))}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for your selector?

Comment: I edit the post to include the initial state and selectors code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing the component update in the dev tools but it's not re-rendering, then the problem is likely the way the store has been wired up to the `ToDoList` component.

[Here's a StackBlitz showing the code all wired together](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ayjarg?file=src%2FToDo.jsx) - I created a simple "host" component which uses your `selectToDos` selector to wire up the store to the `ToDoList` -

```
function ToDoListHost() {
  const toDos = useSelector(selectToDos);

  return (
    <ToDoList toDos={toDos} />
  );
}
```

I also changed the `ToDo` component a little bit so that each update is immediately propagated to the store by hooking up the `onChange` event in the input field:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { editToDo, deleteToDo } from './store';

export default function ToDo({ id, text }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = event => 
    dispatch(editToDo({ id, text: event.target.value }));

  return (
    <>
      <div className="input-group mt-3">
        <input 
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          value={text}
          onChange={handleChange} 
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={() => dispatch(deleteToDo(id))}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```